# Numbering coincidence in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list with the following structure:

```
A1, B2, C3, 66
A1, B2, C3, 00
A2, B2, C3, 77
A3, B3, C4, 44
A4, B4, C5, 11
A4, B4, C5, 12
A4, B4, C5, 13
```

And I need to enumerate the unique `1-3` column elements to get the output like this:

```
A1, B2, C3, 66, 1
A1, B2, C3, 00, 2
A2, B2, C3, 77, 1
A3, B3, C4, 44, 1
A4, B4, C5, 11, 1
A4, B4, C5, 12, 2
A4, B4, C5, 13, 3
```

As you understand, I want the ordinal number in the fourth column to order on unique value at `1-3` columns.

After reading the instructions, I came to the conclusion that I need to use the `collections` module. Is this the right decision?

I try this:

```
new = ['A1,B2,C3,66','A1,B2,C3,00','A2, B2, C3, 77','A3, B3, C4, 44','A4, B4, C5, 11','A4, B4, C5, 12','A4, B4, C5, 13']
test=[]
i = 0
for a in new:
    i+=1
    test.append('{},{}'.format(i, a))
    print(test)
    if a[i]!=a[i-1]:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
import re
new = ['A1,B2,C3,66','A1,B2,C3,00','A2, B2, C3, 77','A3, B3, C4, 44','A4, B4, C5, 11','A4, B4, C5, 12','A4, B4, C5, 13']
n = map(lambda x:re.split(',\s*', x), new)
s = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(n, key=lambda x:x[:-1])]
last_data = map(lambda x:', '.join(x[:-1]+[str(x[-1])]), [i for b in [[b+[i] for i, b in enumerate(c, start=1)] for c in s] for i in b])
```

Output:

```
['A1, B2, C3, 66, 1', 
'A1, B2, C3, 00, 2', 
'A2, B2, C3, 77, 1', 
'A3, B3, C4, 44, 1', 
'A4, B4, C5, 11, 1', 
'A4, B4, C5, 12, 2', 
'A4, B4, C5, 13, 3']
```

Comment: But I do not understand where in your code you separate 1-3 columns from 4?

Comment: @Misha1991 This code relies on the fact that there is an arbitrary number of columns. In your provided input, for example, the maximum number of columns is 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to doing `group by` by yourself, below is one option (not perfect solution).

It uses one dict named `index_cache` to store the occurrences count of one key. Then leverage this dict to get the expected value when loop.

```
import re
test = ['A1,B2,C3,66','A1,B2,C3,00','A2, B2, C3, 77','A3, B3, C4, 44','A4, B4, C5, 11','A4, B4, C5, 12','A4, B4, C5, 13']
index_cache = {} #store all occurrences count for each key

def prepare(data):
    formatted = re.split(',\s*', data.strip())
    index_cache['-'.join(formatted[:3])] = 0 # init the count to 0
    return formatted

test1 = list(map(prepare, test))

for item in test1:
    index_cache['-'.join(item[:3])] += 1
    item.append(index_cache['-'.join(item[:3])])
print (test1)
```

Output:

```
[['A1', 'B2', 'C3', '66', 1], ['A1', 'B2', 'C3', '00', 2], ['A2', 'B2', 'C3', '77', 1], ['A3', 'B3', 'C4', '44', 1], ['A4', 'B4', 'C5', '11', 1], ['A4', 'B4', 'C5', '12', 2], ['A4', 'B4', 'C5', '13', 3]]
[Finished in 0.209s]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to code this without going to `itertools`. `itertools` can be faster -don't know, need to test- but this is way easier to read/understand/manipulate. Your rule of enumeration is very clear: For each element in my list named `new`, increase the index by 1 if its first three items are the same as the first three of the previous element in my list. If they are different, break the sequence and start over from 1.

Here is the code:

```
new = ['A1, B2, C3, 66','A1, B2, C3, 00','A2, B2, C3, 77','A3, B3, C4, 44','A4, B4, C5, 11','A4, B4, C5, 12','A4, B4, C5, 13']
result = []
prev = None
c = 1
for x in new:
    current = ", ".join(x.split(", ")[:3])
    if current == prev:
        c += 1
    else:
        c = 1
    result.append(", ".join((x, str(c))))
    prev = current
```